# How to put values "behind" the cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am doing a calculator in Excel and I would like to do the following thing:

I have cells with drop down lists with "Y" and "N".
I would like to assign the values to these letters/cells, but with keeping letters but without showing the numbers (calculator is divided into 3 sections and depends on section of the calculator, different values will be applied for "Y" and "N").
The final step is to get the total sum of these cells.

Does anyone have an idea how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?
Hint, you need to use an IF statement. In this case, it should be very simple.

Comment: But first I want to put values behind the letters, and then base on it make a subtotal/total

Comment: Use an IF statement where you have your "Subtotal" something like IF(A1="Y";12;0) will be what you need. In this case your Y or N needs to be in cell A1, if it has a value of Y then it will give you 12, if it has any other value then you have a value 0.

Try for yourself and see where you get stuck, then edit your question and someone will answer the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this would be to create a second sheet that includes all the 'maths work' using the IF() functions. Then hide this sheet by right clicking on the tab at the bottom and select hide

For example, on Sheet2 use `=IF(Sheet1!C3="Y",50,0)`  (where 50 is the price for that option if true and 0 is the option if not true) do this for all your Y & N options, do the maths work on this second sheet ie) `=SUM(C4, C6, C8)`

finally just pull the answer onto your front page by having in your totals boxes `=Sheet2!B10` where B10 is the location of the answer you require.